# Python calling subprocess of a bash script in sudo

Tags: python, bash, unix, ssh, raspberry-pi

I'm running a python script on my rPi. I have to run it in sudo to use the rpi.gpio library, but when I do, it won't let me run my bash script in non-sudo. This causes my ssh commands to prompt for passwords, even though the key-gen authentication is set.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple. Can anyone help?

Running python script:

```
sudo python ./runcam.py
```

In the py script I'm running this:

```
subprocess.call("./runit", shell=True)
```

And my ssh script:

```
#!/bin/bash

      FNAME=`date +'%H-%M-%S-%m%d%Y'`

      ssh pi@192.168.0.8 '
        mkdir $FNAME
      ' & 

      ssh pi@192.168.0.9 '
        mkdir $FNAME
      ' &
```

Comment: Could you change your command to `subprocess.call("sudo ./runit", shell=True)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also drop your root permissions with sudo. You just need to check for user id 0, and the environment variable "SUDO_USER", then `sudo -u "$SUDO_USER" command`.

You can do it in your bash script like this:

```
# if we're root from sudo, run this script as the original user instead
[[ "$(id -u)" = "0" && -n "${SUDO_USER:-}" ]] && exec sudo -u "$SUDO_USER" "$0" "$@"
```

Full script example:

```
#!/bin/bash -u
[[ "$(id -u)" = "0" && -n "${SUDO_USER:-}" ]] && exec sudo -u "$SUDO_USER" "$0" "$@"
id -u
```

This script will print *your* user id, regardless of whether it's run with sudo.